# Invalid traffic coming from Sogou

Tags: web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, google-adsense, security, user-agent

I have not indexed my website in Sogou. I have only very less visitors. But i am getting traffic from Sogou daily. The search keyword is "site:mywebsitename" and is from China. Just visiting main page. I don't how this happen. I am planning to apply adsense. Will this traffic become a problem. Is it fake?

Comment: If the user comes daily and you have few traffic, you could investigate, find its IP in access logs and block it via htaccess or whatever. It may be a robot or a scrapping script using different IPs so the hard way would be to block the referrer globally. But it would affect all users coming from Sogou.

Comment: @gael, the IP address are different. Will this affects Adsense?

Comment: I don't think it will affect Adsense and I'm sure they have a support team that would help you if it is a problem. But if those visits really bother you, and you don't target chinese visitors, you can still block all visitors coming from Sogou. It should stop the spam